# How to develop Microsoft Teams app for "App Bar and home screen"

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to create an application for Microsoft Teams but I don't understand what capability I have to exploit.
I would like the application to be called up from the application bar and opened to full screen.
The same behavior that occurs for the "App Studio" application.
I need to bring something that is not accessible, either by chat or tea; the app should manage a flow in a personal window.

I looked at the manifest definition document but found nothing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

I would like to replicate the application behavior like AppStudio or Microsoft Planner, to name a few.
For example [App Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PveL.png)

A possible alternative, could be to insert a button in the chats and open a popup with the configuration page.
I saw this behavior for the AzureDevOps extension.
Unfortunately this also seems to be a capability not available.
[Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wu1i.png)

Do you have any idea how to do it?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct solution is static tab for personal use.
[Complete answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/How-to-develop-Microsoft-Teams-app-for-App-Bar-and-home-screen/m-p/679550)